# Laravel model observer repository injection

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, repository

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to inject Laravel's model observers with repositories.
Currently, I have this setup.

UserPetServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Bunny\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Bunny\Observers\Pet\UserPetObserver;

class UserPetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        // User pets
        $this->app->bind('Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetRepo', 'Bunny\Repos\Pet\UserPetRepo');

        // User pet layers
        $this->app->bind('Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetLayerRepo', 'Bunny\Repos\Pet\UserPetLayerRepo');

        // User pet markings
        $this->app->bind('Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetMarkingRepo', 'Bunny\Repos\Pet\UserPetMarkingRepo');

        $this->app->events->subscribe(new UserPetObserver());
    }

}
```

It binds all the interfaces and repositories fine and would with the observer, but I need repository injection which I do in the constructor. Nothing is being passed in the constructor so it would explain why it fails.

UserPetRepo.php

```
<?php namespace Bunny\Repos\Pet;

use Bunny\Repos\BaseRepo;
use Bunny\Models\Pet\UserPet;
use Bunny\Repos\User\IUserRepo;
use Bunny\Repos\Breed\IStageRepo;
use Bunny\Repos\Breed\IBreedLayerRepo;

use Illuminate\Config\Repository as Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Str as String;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager as Session;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

class UserPetRepo extends BaseRepo implements IUserPetRepo {

    public function __construct(UserPet $pet, IUserRepo $user, IStageRepo $stage, IBreedLayerRepo $layer, Config $config, String $string, Session $session, Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $this->model = $pet;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->stage = $stage;
        $this->layer = $layer;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->events = $events;

        $this->directory = $this->config->get('pathurl.userpets');
        $this->url       = $this->config->get('pathurl.userpets_url');
    }

    /**
     * Create new user pet
     * @param attributes     Attributes
     */
    public function createWithImage( array $attributes, array $colors, $domMarkings = null, $domMarkingColors = null, $recMarkings = null, $recMarkingColors = null )
    {
        $this->model->name = $attributes['name'];
        $this->model->breed_id = $attributes['breed_id'];
        $this->model->user_id = $this->user->getId();
        $this->model->stage_id = $this->stage->getBaby()->id;

        // Get image
        $image = $this->layer->compile(
            $attributes['breed_id'],
            'baby',
            $colors,
            $domMarkings,
            $domMarkingColors
        );

        // Write image and set
        $file = $this->writeImage( $image );
        if( ! $file )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->model->base_image = $file;
        $this->model->image = $file;

        if( ! $this->model->save() )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->events->fire('userpet.create', array($this->model));

        return $this->model;
    }

    /**
     * Write image
     * @param image      Imagick Object
     */
    protected function writeImage( $image )
    {
        $fileName = $this->string->random(50) . '.png';

        if( $image->writeImage( $this->directory . $fileName ) )
        {
            return $fileName;
        }

        $this->model->errors()->add('writeImage', 'There was an error writing your image. Please contact an administrator');
        return false;
    }

}
```

UserPetObserver.php

```
use Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetLayerRepo;
use Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetMarkingRepo;
use Bunny\Observers\BaseObserver;

class UserPetObserver extends BaseObserver {

    public function __construct(IUserPetLayerRepo $layers, IUserPetMarkingRepo $markings)
    {
        $this->layers = $layers;
        $this->markings = $markings;
    }

    /**
     * After create
     */
    public function onCreate( $model )
    {
        $this->layers->user_pet_id = $model->id;
        dd(Input::all());
        $this->layers->breed_layer_id = $model->id;
    }

    public function subscribe( $event )
    {
        $event->listen('userpet.create', 'UserPetObserver@onCreate');
    }

}
```

It throws this as the error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Bunny\Observers\Pet\UserPetObserver::__construct() must be an instance
>   of Bunny\Repos\Pet\IUserPetLayerRepo, none given, called in H:\WD
>   SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source2\bunny-meadows\app\Bunny\Providers\UserPetServiceProvider.php
>   on line 22 and defined

Which makes sense since I'm not passing anything in the constructor. So I try to pass my repository manually.

```
$this->app->events->subscribe(new UserPetObserver(new UserPetLayerRepo, new UserPetMarkingRepo));
```

But then it throws errors of UserPetLayerRepo needing injections... and it just chains on and on. Is there anyway of doing this that I'm just overthinking?

Thanks.

EDIT:::
This is the only thing I could think of doing. This seems like a really ugly/bad way of doing it though:

```
$this->app->events->subscribe(new UserPetObserver($this->app->make('Bunny\Repos\Pet\UserPetLayerRepo'), $this->app->make('Bunny\Repos\Pet\UserPetMarkingRepo')));
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just:

```
$this->app->events->subscribe($this->app->make('UserPetObserver'));
```

When Laravel makes the `UserPetObserver` object, it will read the type-hinted dependencies in the constructor and automatically make them, as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! I don't know why I didn't think of that after I passed in $this->app->make() as the arguments for that constructor D: Too much coding for one day lol

Comment: Do you know why whenever I try to inject a repository that isn't in the same register() method, it gives me this: Class cache.store does not exist. ? I have this in my constructor: `public function __construct(IUserPetLayerRepo $layers, IUserPetMarkingRepo $markings, IBreedLayerRepo $breedLayers)` It works fine if I remove IBreedLayerRepo.. it's not in the same register() because it's in another service provider.

Comment: I imagine in that case it is because IBreedLayerRepo depends on the cache store, and your service provider's register function is getting called before the cache store has been loaded. In reality, your event listener should not be called in the `register` method. You should override the `boot` method and add your event listener there. Docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#basic-provider-example).

Comment: Whenever I move it there, I get an error message. `public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->subscribe($this->app->make('Bunny\Observers\Pet\UserPetObserver'));
    }`

It says the boot method must be compatible with ServiceProvider::boot() from the Illuminate/Support. I looked at their code and nothing is being passed in the boot() so how do you build dependencies in there?

Comment: $this->app->events did the trick.. but it's just weird that you can't inject stuff into the boot() when they show that in the docs. Oh well (: Thanks a lot! That fixed the cache.store issue.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I wasn't paying attention and the docs I linked to were for Laravel 5. The 4.2 docs are [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#service-providers). But, as you've already found out, there is no parameter to the boot method in Laravel 4. Glad you got it working, though!